# Elegant way of selections in Qt

Tags: forms, qt, user-interface, c++11, radio-button

I have a program where user selects from 4 options (A, B, C, D). After selecting an option, user can either select again from these options or end the selection progress.

I am thinking of displaying the options with radio buttons and prompting the user if s/he wants to select more options with a pop-up window.

But, is there a better way of achieving this task?

Comment: Checkboxes instead of radio buttons would allow the user to arbitrarily select zero, one, many, or all without any prompting. Do you need to limit the selection for some reason?

Comment: @Steve User can select from 4 of these options as many as s/he wants. But system needs to prompt if user wants to continue selection or end the process.

Comment: Radio buttons imply only one selection is valid. You can "code around" that, but don't -- it's universally understood that a radio button group is single-selection only. Use checkboxes and fire an event that one was selected and do your prompting there. Out of curiosity, why would anyone want to prompt someone after every selection like that, rather than a "select all that apply...." scenario? I'm just curious, is all.

Comment: @mrunion This seems not widely understood that circular check mark in radio button is for single selection, which check mark is for multiple selection. One of my co-worker made a multiple select radio button group and confuses nobody around but me, strange.

Comment: Back to this question, I would use a button to start/stop selection, and another to commit selection. Or one button to start/commit, another to cancel. I don't think there is a convenient check box version of radio button. You probably need to write your own. Don't try to hack radio button's indicator to a checkmark. Just don't do it.

Comment: I would use checkboxes, as it is typical for radiobuttons that only one is selectable at a time but checkboxes are independent options when in a row/column. You could even provide a "select all" checkbox beneath the others, to show that multiple option selection is an option

Comment: @supaplex Why does the user need to be prompted if they want to continue or not? Simply let them continue to make selections as long as they want, then when they click a button ("OK", "Next", ...) they are signalling to you to proceed. Maybe your question is how to present them a dialog box after they hit OK that says "Are you sure you want these selections?".

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether the user should be able to select multiple options in a single selection. If so, use check boxes, otherwise - radio buttons or a combo box.

I think prompting the user after each selection with a pop up window is both irritating for the user and also would be much more complicated to implement in code.